# Using AngularJS to show divs based on select value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select, ng-show

I'm trying to use an HTML `select` element's value to show or hide certain `div` tags with AngularJS. Here is my code:

```
<body ng-app="kiosk" id="ng-app" >
    <div class="page" ng-controller="kiosk-controller" ng-cloak="true">
        <section class="signin">

        <div class="intro">
            <h1 id="service-desk-name">{{servicedeskname}}</h1><br></br>
            <h4 id="welcome">{{welcome}}</h4>
        </div>

        <hr></hr>

        <form id="form" name="form">

            <div>
                <label>Do you have an ID?</label><br></br>
                <select type="select" 
                    ng-model="user.affiliated"
                    ng-required="true"
                    ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in affiliate.affiliateOptions">
                    <option value="">--Select an answer--</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div ng-switch="user.affiliated">

            <div ng-switch-when="Yes"> 
                <!--><-->
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="No">
                <!--><-->
            </div>

            </div>
```

And here is the Javascript snippet:

```
var kiosk = angular.module('kiosk',[]);

kiosk.controller('kiosk-controller', ['$scope', function($scope, $user) {
    $scope.servicedeskname = 'Service Desk';
    $scope.welcome = 'Please sign in and a consultant will be with you shortly.';

    $scope.affiliate = {affiliateOptions:[]};
    $scope.affiliate.affiliateOptions = [
        { name: 'Yes' },
        { name: 'No' }
    ];
/*other stuff*/
};
```

I can't figure out the proper way to reference the select options in the HTML tags using `ng` directives. Unless it's not super clear, I want to be able to show one `div` if the select value is "Yes", and show another if the select value is "No".

Answer (score 1):

I think the switch statement you use need small modification

```
<div ng-switch on="user.affiliated">

            <div ng-switch-when="Yes"> 
                <!--><-->
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="No">
                <!--><-->
            </div>
</div>
```

[check this ng-switch documentation for more help](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for ng-show and ng-hide.

```
            <div ng-show="user.affiliated === 'Yes'"></div>
            <div ng-show="user.affiliated === 'No'"></div>
```

And try changing this line to this:

```
            ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in affiliate.affiliateOptions">
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried using that as well. I think the problem is that I don't know what to use on the left-hand side or what to use for the expression on the right-hand side to access the things I'm wanting to test against. I will try again and see if I was just doing something wrong.

Comment: It still is not working. The page loads with neither divs being shown, and regardless of which option I click, they both stay invisible.

Comment: @UnworthyToast the first thing in the statement of ng-options is the value the <select> gets.
The second is what's displayed.
The third is the actual object in the ng-option
The last is the thing being iterated over.

Try changing the line to what I put above.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `name` property in the switch statement.

```
-    <div ng-switch="user.affiliated">
+    <div ng-switch="user.affiliated.name">
```

As can be viewed in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12ndy14m/)

Answer (score 0):

you just have a little mistake. you must have user.affiliated.name instead of user.affiliated

```
like this 

<div ng-switch="user.affiliated.name">

        <div ng-switch-when="Yes"> 
           yes
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="No">
            no
        </div>

    </div>
```